# Magento: Override their Address when Pickup at Store is selected

Tags: php, magento

What I am looking for is a way to override their own address they have with the stores address when they choose pickup at store. The tax at that point should not be based off of their address, but the store itself.

Now this is for the "Estimate Shipping and Tax" section on the Shopping Cart only. I did find code that allowed this to properly work on the Checkout side which was more important, but this didn't take care of the Shopping Cart section.

The code I am using is found here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/collect-in-store-checkout-shipping-option.html

Even if someone can point me in the right direction on how this was done on the Checkout side and implement that into the Shopping Cart side, that would be a big help.